# What is the relationship between Rotational speed (RPM) and the speed of a drone (Air speed)

Tags: dynamics

I would like to know whats the relationship between these two, is it linear? or what? also i would like to know the mathematical relationship between these two. Thank you

Comment: I think you could improve your question by explaining what rotational speed you are considering and what type of drone (quad-coptor, plane, helicoptor, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to rotational speed (rpm) of the Unmanned Air Vehicle's (UAV) motors versus the air speed of the UAV, there are other variables involved.

This includes the specific geometry of the UAV, all-up weight including selected battery, aerodynamics and number of motors installed. The propeller diameter and pitch is critical to the operation of the UAV and will change the performance of the vehicle.

There are many factors to complicate a mathematical relationship. I suspect that designers use a method involving trial and error as much as anything mathematical.